# How to use restricted characters in egrep?

Tags: centos, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to use a regex in egrep on Centos 5.10, based on the one I made from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298583/how-to-set-maximum-number-of-wildcard-characters-in-a-regex) on SO.

```
T12345 .{1,100}[\n\r].{1,100}2014.03.04
```

I can successfully match the regex to the content in my browser, but when I try it in an egrep, nothing is returned, even though there are several matches in my directory.

[Working Regex Example here](http://regex101.com/r/nK0iB2)

Here is the egrep as I'm using it.

```
egrep -l "T12345 .{1,100}[\n\r].{1,100}2014.03.04" logfiles_*.txt
```

As far as I can tell, I'm not escaping the restricted characters properly, but nothing I've tried seems to work. ***How can I adapt this regex for use in egrep?***

Comment: `grep` operates on lines, and your expression will never match a single line.

Comment: As an aside, please post more information in your questions.  [In your previous question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298583/how-to-set-maximum-number-of-wildcard-characters-in-a-regex), you should have mentioned that you are using `grep`.  If a solution did not work for you, what prompted you to accept the answer and post a question on a different site?

Comment: Replace `egrep -l` with `pcregrep -Ml`

Comment: @devnull Because I tried to avoid asking a multipart question equivalent to "just do this for me". I like to abstract questions so they are more widely useful too. Regexes are not just used by egrep in Linux, so if another person finds that question they can use the answer. Also now I know the regex works, I tried to implement it myself. I couldn't, so now the implementation in Centos is the problem, it becomes a question suitable for U&L.

Comment: @blarg The reason for the comment was simply to state that the implementation of regular expressions varies from language to language.  As such, the solutions for different languages might be rather different!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grep` matches *lines* of input.  If you want to match over multiple lines, use another utility.  For example, use `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M "T12345 .{1,100}[\n\r].{1,100}2014.03.04" filename
```

This would produce:

```
31/01/2014 11:15:40 |  Bla Bla Bla Bla T12345 Bla Bla Bla
31/01/2014 11:15:40 | Bla Bla Bla 2014/03/04 Bla Bla Bla
```

for your input.

Comment: (bearing in mind that `.` above would _not_ match a newline character)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, I assumed that the regex is intended for matching over two lines!  (From the linked question on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that egrep and grep normally reads a single line and then compare to the given regexp.

To make your regexp solutions works, you need the -z option for egrep.

> `-z, --null-data`
>                 Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero
>                 byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.   Like  the
>                 -Z  or --null option, this option can be used with commands like
>                 sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

So try this:
`egrep -l -z "T12345 .{1,100}\s+.{1,100}2014.03.04" logfiles_*.txt`

Comment: `\s+` will match any whitespace, not `\r` and `\n` specifically.